# Finding radius of convergence on a Banach space

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, power-series, banach-spaces

> Let $(\phi_m)$ be the sequence of coordinate functionals on $\ell^p$ where $1\leq p <\infty.$ Then the power series $\sum_{m=0}^\infty (\phi_m(x))^m$ is absolutely convergent for any $x\in\ell^p$ but the radius of convergence is $1$.

Here, the definition of power series is : A power series from the Banach space $X$ to $\mathbb C$ is a series of the form $\sum_{m=0}^\infty P_m(x-a)$ where $(P_m)$ is a sequence of polynomials from $X^m$ to $\mathbb C$. Radius of convergence for this series is defined as $R=\frac{1}{\limsup_{m \to\infty}\|P_m\|^{1/m}}$ by the Cauchy-Hadamard formula.

I also have the following lemma :

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $\phi \in X^*$ with $\|\phi\|=1$. Then $P:=\phi^m$ is a polynomial from $X^m$ to $\mathbb C$ with $\|P\|=1$.

Absolute convergence is ok. I am trying to see that it is a power series (please note that it is not a classical power series, I added my definition above) and also state its radius of convergence.

My thoughts : Since coordinate functionals are linear and continuous, we have $(\phi_m)\subset {\ell^p}^*$. Also, I showed $\|\phi_m\|=1$ for each $m$. Then by the previous lemma each $P_m:=\phi_m^m$ is a polynomial from ${(\ell^p)}^m$ to $\mathbb C$ and $\|P_m\|=1$. Hence, given series is a power series and by the Cauchy-Hadamard formula, its radius of convergence is $R=\frac{1}{\limsup_{m \to\infty}\|P_m\|^{1/m}}=\frac{1}{\limsup_{m \to\infty}1^{1/m}}=1$.

I am not sure about whether my thoughts are true. I appreciate any correction or suggestion.

Thank you and merry xmas

Edit : Definition of a polynomial from $X$ to $\mathbb C$: A mapping $P:X\to\mathbb C$ is a polynomial if there exists a multi-linear map from $X^m$ to $\mathbb C$ such that $P(x)=Ax^m$ for every $x\in X$. ($x^m$ is a notation here, it means that $x^m=(x,x,\dots, x)$-m times $x$)

Comment: What is a "polynomial from $X^m$ to $\mathbb C$"?

Comment: I am sorry, I added the definition

Comment: How can a series absolutely converge everywhere but have radius of convergence one? That tells you, the definition of radius of convergence isn’t a good one.

Comment: Unfortunately, most of sources on holomorphy I’ve seen use these definitions. Do you think that I have a mistake?